# Installing make with MobaXterm

Tags: makefile, installation

Here is the command I'm running

```
apt-get install make
```

Here is the error output I'm getting

```
Found package make
Installing make
Unpacking make-4.2.1-1.tar.xz...
Extracting dependencies for usr/bin/make.exe...
Package make requires the following packages, installing cygwin libguile17 libintl8
Package cygwin is already installed, skipping
Found package libguile17

Installing libguile17
Downloading libguile17-1.8.8-1.tar.xz...
Downloading /home/mobaxterm/.aptcyg/http%3a%2f%2fmirrors.kernel.org%2fsourceware%2fcygwin/release/libguile17/libguile17-1.8.8-1.tar.xz using Windows internet settings
sha512sum: can't open 'libguile17-1.8.8-1.tar.xz': No such file or directory
/bin/apt-cyg: line 476: test:   94f5e268a2f32d7c6b19747792a18d13f468779daca46bdd20aa99d63931c4fe8071a460e62db9d1779b15fee167ce7c6c65a0e90e61225cf8be12e3a14a2252: unary operator expected
md5sum: can't open 'libguile17-1.8.8-1.tar.xz': No such file or directory
/bin/apt-cyg: line 479: test: 94f5e268a2f32d7c6b19747792a18d13f468779daca46bdd20aa99d63931c4fe8071a460e62db9d1779b15fee167ce7c6c65a0e90e61225cf8be12e3a14a2252: unary operator expected
Checksum did not match, exiting

Found package libintl8
Package libintl8 is already included, skipping
Package make installed.
```

Is there anyone who has GNU make running on MobaXTerm and who would like to help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run this command, it worked for me at least.

```
apt-get --legacy install libguile17
```

Answer (score 0):

I normally collect the Development plugins from http://mobaxterm.mobatek.net/plugins/Development.mxt3

Once the .mxt3 files are getting downloaded, moved them to the installed folder where the MobaXterm_.exe is there, this location could be in Program Files if you are using installer edition or the extracted folder incase of zip.

Please restart the MobaXtern once.

After restarting MobaXterm, this will work like a champ.

Hope if this solves your issue.

Comment: This plugin comes with all dependencies, no need to worry about further dependencies etc.